# Re-upload song to iCloud Music Library

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, apple-music, itunes-match

There's a few songs that I've added to iCloud Music Library using iTunes on my PC but it seems that some of them didn't upload correctly because (1) they never play past a certain point on my iPhone and (2) deleting and re-adding them to my library on my iPhone doesn't made a difference.

So, how do you re-upload a song to iCloud Music Library? Preferrably without removing it from my iTunes library as I assume that this will delete the play count.

I've tried using `File` | `Library` | `Update iCloud Music Library`.